# Magento 2 Patch MDVA-449 SSH Command

Tags: magento2, patches, ssh

I have followed these instructions to apply the above patch - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/tech_bull_207-upgrade.html and on the bottom it instructs to execute the command

`cp -R magento2-updater-10.0.2/* update/`

which copies files from one directory to the other. However, I received over 50 prompts asking me if I want to overwrite the current file. In future, what command do I use so it overwrites all the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

try this:

```
yes | cp -rf magento2-updater-10.0.2/* update/
```

tl;dr

This is probably caused by `cp` being already aliased to something like `cp -i`. Calling `cp` directly should work:

```
/bin/cp -rf magento2-updater-10.0.2/* update/
```

You can check existing aliases by running `alias` at the command prompt, or `which cp` to check aliases only for cp.

If you do have an alias defined, running `unalias cp` will abolish that for the current session, otherwise you can just remove it from your shell profile.

You can temporarily bypass an alias and use the non-aliased version of a command by prefixing it with \, e.g. `\cp whatever`

For more details check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8488292/1016425